# Why do we need to fit the model again in order to get score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-selection

I'm testing the embedded methods for feature selection.

I understand (maybe I misunderstand) that with embedded methods we can get best features (based on importance of the features) while training the model.

Is so, I want to get the score of the trained model (which was trained to select features).

I'm testing that on classification problem with Lasso method.

When I'm trying to get the score, I'm getting error that I need to fit again the model.

1. Why do I need to do it (it seem waste of time if the model was fitted on feature selection ?)
2. Why can't we do it (select features and get model score) in one shot ?
3. Why if we are using embedded method, why do we need to do it  2 phases ? why can't we train the model while choose the best features in one fit ?

   ```
   from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, LogisticRegression
   from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
   estimator = LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty='l1', solver='liblinear')
   selection = SelectFromModel(estimator)
   selection.fit(x_train, y_train)
   print(estimator.score(x_test, y_test))
   ```

Error:

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitted estimator is returned as `selection.estimator_` (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html)); so, after fitting `selection`, you can simply do:

```
selection.estimator_.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: But if we are using embedded method, why do we need to do it  2 phases ? why can't we train the model while choose the best features in one fit ?